# CSS Responsive Image Position

Tags: css

I'm making an animation that I position a `balloon` over a `world map`.
The problem is that the `world map` is responsive (bootstrap class `img-responsive`), so:

How can I position the `balloon` over the `São Paulo` point and it respect all `world map` sizes?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/6j2Bs/1/

Answer (score 6):

You can use percentages to position the balloon: [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j2Bs/2/).

I have also added `width: 15%;` onto the balloon image so that it resizes with the map, you can remove this if you don't want this feature.

Comment: Nice! I did the exact same as you both (closer to @Joseph Marikles with the 52.4%). Post timing is everything :)

Comment: Great minds think alike! Some just more precise than others eh? ;)

Comment: This is from  @JosephMarikle in the event the fiddle disappears in the future:
`#map {
}

.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#balloon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 52.4%;
    width: 15%;
}`